# Search document on file system

Tags: wss, wss-3.0

I have WSS 3.0 installed on my machine. I have installed SearchServer Express 2008. It search from my document library. it is fine. But i want to search from document files that are located on my file system (e.g c:/ResumeRepository) on same machine.

Is there any settings in search server configuration to get this done. It could be very  nice if you could help me out.

Thanks
Sachin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is. In Search Server you have the option to add content sources. A content source can be pretty much anything if you provide a protocol handler for it, but File system searches should work out of the box.
In Search Server -> Search Administration find the link to content sources. ad a new content source wiht a file share as a source.

Also, another option is federated search.